# I am forgetting something at the time I am adding a DLL as reference

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I am trying to use the the WPF Currency textbox for here: https://wpfcurrencytextbox.codeplex.com/documentation and I go in my project and add reference and after I did what the website from the link said to do that is put this code:

```
xmlns:currency="clr-namespace:CurrencyTextBoxControl;assembly=CurrencyTextBoxControl"
```

and this part is ok but when I put the second instruction inside the:

```
<Grid>
    <currency:CurrencyTextBox Number="{Binding Number}" />
</Grid>
```

in this part I have a error:

```
Error 15 The name "CurrencyTextBox" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CurrencyTextBoxControl;assembly=CurrencyTextBoxControl"
```

What could be that I am forgetting?

Answer (score 2):

Did you add a reference to the DLL to the project?  In VS, right click on the "References" folder under your project & select "Add Reference".  Navigate in the dialog to the folder where you placed the DLL and select it.  Make sure it's added to the list of DLLs.  Click OK.

Comment: Yes I added the reference the DLL appear in the list of references but the class is not found! thank you your answer.

Comment: Did you make sure you didn't misspell the assembly or class name in the xmlns: entry of the xaml?

Comment: yes, the only thing that I guess that could be is I am using Framework 4.5.1 and the DLL is 3.5(I think) but I don't know if can be this.